# For Cordova in app purchase, is the sandbox "confirm purchase" screen same as store?

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I'm using the Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-inapppurchase to implement yearly subscriptions for my app.  I'm wondering if the iOS sandbox screens are different than those in production?  I need to reassure my customer that what they're seeing now (for testing) is not what they'll see in production!

In testing in the iOS sandbox, I get this type of screen to confirm my purchase (borrowed from a Ray Wenderlich tutorial) - but I get exactly the same thing.

[image: Sandbox sample "Confirm Purchase"]

I was expecting a screen similar to this.

[image: iOS store sample "Confirm Purchase"]

I've read though the Cordova plugin doc and some tutorials but can't find an answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It changes when it's published and installed through the app store. As long as it's built with Xcode or installed via Testflight it will say [Sandbox] and look different than how you'd expect it to be.

Comment: Great thanks for the quick reply.  That's kind of what I would expect but now I can reassure my customer that it will work correctly.  Too bad the Apple docs don't state that clearly.